# Swift regex for searching format specifiers in a string

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I need help to write the swift regex to find any format specifier in a string.

Eg.

> "I am **%@**. My age is **%d** and my height is **%.02f**."

I need to find all sub-strings in bold and replace them with 'MATCH'

Below is my code

```
var description = "I am %@. My age is %d and my height is %.02f. (%@)"
let pattern = "(%[@df])"
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let nsrange = NSRange(description.startIndex..<description.endIndex, in: description)

while let match = regex.firstMatch(in: description, options: [], range: nsrange) {
    description = (description as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: match.range, with: "MATCH")
}
print(description)
```

and output

```
I am MATCH. My age is MATCH and my height is %.02f. (%@)
```

It did not find **%.02f** and last **%@** with paranthesis.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try anything? At least for your sample values?

Comment: @Larme I have updated the question with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to replace the matches reversed otherwise you will run into index trouble.

A possible pattern is

```
%([.0-9]+)?[@df]
```

it considers also the (optional) decimal places specifier.

```
var description = "I am %@. My age is %d and my height is %.02f. (%@)"
let pattern = "%([.0-9]+)?[@df]"
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
let nsrange = NSRange(description.startIndex..., in: description)

for match in regex.matches(in: description, range: nsrange).reversed() {
    let range = Range(match.range, in: description)!
    description.replaceSubrange(range, with: "MATCH")
}
print(description)
```